# Recursively calculate the number of permutations that have a maximal displacement

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, permutation

I created a recursive function called permutations_dist(s, dist).

It's supposed to return the number of the permutations of a string, while the distance between every 2 letters in the permutations doesn't exceed a given number.

A few examples:

```
permutations_dist("abc", 1) --> 2
permutations_dist("abc", 1000) --> 6
permutations_dist("abcz", 23) --> 4
```

How can I make the following code more efficient?
I want to use backtracking.

It reaches maximum recursion depth pretty quickly. For instance -  `permutations_dist("abcdefghijkm", 3))`.

The CODE:

```
def permutations_dist(s, dist):
    return len(permutations_dist_helper(s, dist))

def permutations_dist_helper(s, dist):
   if len(s) == 1:
       return [s]

   perm_list = []  # resulting list
   for a in s:
       remaining_elements = [x for x in s if x != a]
       z = permutations_dist_helper(remaining_elements, dist)

       for t in z:
           if abs(ord(a) - ord(t[0])) <= dist:
               perm_list.append([a] + t)

    return perm_list
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use stack to avoid exceeding max recursion depth.
The code below generates all string permutations having max distance between two any adjacent characters not more than *dist*:

```
def permutations(s, dist):
    result = set()
    stack = [("", s, 0)]

    while stack:
        cur, remaining, cur_distance = stack.pop(0)

        if remaining:
            candidates = set()
            for i in range(0, len(remaining)):
                m = remaining[i]
                diff = abs(ord(m) - ord(cur[-1])) if cur else 0
                new_distance = max(cur_distance, diff)
                if new_distance <= dist:
                    head = cur + m
                    candidates.add((head, remaining[:i] + remaining[i+1:], new_distance))
            for c in candidates:
                stack.append(c)
        else:
            result.add(cur)

    return result
```

Let's check how long it takes to calculate *permutations("abcdefghijk", 3)*:

```
from time import time
start = time()
dist = len(permutations("abcdefghijk", 3))
end = time()
print("Premutations: {}, execution time: {:05f}".format(dist, end - start))
```

On my MacBook it displays

```
Premutations: 13592, execution time: 0.663339
```

Comment: Thank you but I need it to be more effective by using backtracking. It still cannot make the call permutations_dist("abcdefghijk", 3)

Comment: @ical Well, I improved it to dynamically calculate distances and now it takes 0.66s to run your example.